# Prioritize imports with gopls

Tags: go, neovim, gopls, goimports

Is there any way to specifically set what imports for gopls (the Go language server) to prioritize?

For example, when adding an "assert" in a new test file, I always want `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` and never `atomicgo.dev/assert` but gopls seems to just randomly import one that fits and I need to manually change it afterwards.

Comment: The first time yes, it does seem to "learn" to pick the right one when you use the package in multiple source files. I have this problem when modules have a v1, v2, v3, etc., if I want a /v2 version the first time it always auto-imports the v1 version. Kind of annoying.